# Ant Path error when performing Apache Cordova Helloworld example for amazon-fireos

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, ant

I am working through [Apache Cordova Amazon-fireos guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_amazonfireos_index.md.html#Amazon%20Fire%20OS%20Platform%20Guide)

But I am getting an Ant path error when performing "cordova platform add amazon-fireos" command. Looking at the code it looks like it is doing a pre-req check and trying to execute ant -version but failing. I then tried skipping that pre-req only for it to then error out when it tries to execute java -version. But after the cordova command errors out I can type ant -version and java -version and both commands execute successfully, see screenshot below.

[image: Screen shot of command prompt with cordova error and successful run of ant -version command]

I am running Windows 7 Pro 64bit and my path variables looks like this:
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
ANT_HOME = c:\apache-ant-1.9.3

PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs;%ANDROID_HOME%;%ANDROID_TOOLS%;
C:\Users\Super\AppData\Roaming\npm;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

Here is the screenshot from running the command with the -d option.

[image: Cordova command with -d option]

Comment: I have the same error when I do cordova platform add android

Comment: Can you run cordova -d platform add amazon-fireos and paste the logs?

Comment: I have run the command with the -d option and included the console output. Is there supposed to be a log file I should look for or is it just the console output in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I must of accidently deleted c:\windows\system32 from the PATH variable and so it could not find the cmd command. Added the path c:\windows\system32 back in and I no longer receive the Ant error.